# Setting up client side certificate for mutual authentication

Tags: ssl

I am trying to set up 2 way ssl mutual authentication for my web application. I currently haven't set up my client and am testing my web service through my browser.

I created a client certificate using the keychain tool on my mac and import the certificate.p12 file in Firefox. I also have a certificate.cert file. From my understanding I need to add this cert file in my servers truststore.

For that I need to using the following command:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias <hostname of DP> -file <your file.crt> -keystore <truststorefile>
```

However what do I add as the hostname of my system? What will the browser show the hostname as to my webserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if you have client cert(s) issued by either a well-known CA (like Verisign, GoDaddy, etc) or a locally-trusted one (like your employer), you don't have to do anything. The client will simply present the cert with a chain that leads to the already-trusted CA.

If you have issued client certs from your own CA, you should add the *CA (root) cert only* to the server truststore. Then all client certs issued by that CA will be validated without further effort. If you make the CA cert long-lived, as is the usual practice, you can even renew and/or replace client certs with no effort on the server. And you can automatically revoke them if you set up CRL distribution and/or OCSP, although DIY CAs don't always want to go to that effort.

If you have created a self-signed client cert, then and only then you need to add that specific cert to the server truststore. Although SSL/TLS *server certs* must be identified by the hostname(s) of the server, client certs are not required to, and CA certs (which are the certs usually in your truststore by default) never have a hostname as the Subject (although some extensions usually contain URLs that *contain* hostnames). Codesigning certs also don't need to use a hostname.

The alias of a cert entry in a Java truststore does not need to be the hostname; it only *needs* to be unique, although it *should* be mnemonic of the subject of the cert. If for example your client certs are for users named Alice and Bob (or more likely their PCs or whatever devices) you can just use `alice` and `bob` as the aliases.